# c++ boost log: How to filter by using own modules?

Tags: c++, logging, boost

My program has different "modules". A module consists of some classes that belong together. To give some examples, module names are *network*, *file* or *renderer*. How can I add a module information to boost log allowing to filter for these modules? Something like the following (note: this approach is not working):

**Configuring:**

```
enum modules {
    network,
    file,
    renderer
};

template< typename CharT, typename TraitsT >
inline std::basic_ostream< CharT, TraitsT >& operator<< (
std::basic_ostream< CharT, TraitsT >& strm, modules lvl)
{
     static const char* const str[] =
     {
        "network",
        "file",
        "renderer"
    };

    if (static_cast< std::size_t >(lvl) < (sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str))) {
       strm << str[lvl];
    } else {
        strm << static_cast< int >(lvl);
    }

    return strm;
}

// Formatting this somehow
keywords::format = expr::stream
        << [" << expr::attr< severity_level >("Severity")
        << "] [" << expr::attr< modules >("Modules")
        << "] " << expr::message
```

**Usage:**

```
logging::core::get()->set_filter(expr::attr< modules >("Modules") = network | renderer);
// Will be visible
BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, lvl)<< network << "Network down!";
// Will not be visible since set_filter has been configured to drop all "file" messages
BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, lvl)<< file << "Hard disk problem!";
```

This is of course not working. But what would be the correct way to setup this.